# Объдиненные запросы в MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

До этого че-то не приходилось углубляться в БД, а вот сейчас тренируюсь на разработке форума, и застрял. Есть как минимум 2 таблицы - в одной список тем форума, дат и айди авторов. Во второй - сами профили авторов. Нужно вывести список : автор, тема, дата.

```
$query = "SELECT user_id,topic,date FROM table ";
```

Такая постановка запроса вернет айди юзеров, а нужно-то вывести их имена, находящиеся в другой таблице. Подскажите на этом примере как это делается. Пожалуйста.

Comment: sqlfidle сделайте, структуру таблиц обоих неплохо было-бы выдать.

Comment: @eicto, здравствуйте! Никогда с sqlfidle не работал.(( Все упрощено до минимума. 1 таблица - поля topic,user_id,date.

2 таблица - user_id,name.
Все

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ так начните.
в левой форме поставьте `CREATE TABLE` и `INSERT` в правой запросы.

видимо ответ на ваш вопрос 

SELECT t.topic,t.date,u.name FROM topics t, users u where t.user_id=u.user_id;

Comment: @eicto,DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL; А где можно изменить привилегии? Или нужно еще и log in?

Comment: а зачем вам это понадобилось ? я же говорю
INSERT тоже в левой [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/1)

Comment: @eicto, пишет - только select, (only select statements are allowed)

Comment: да, в правой колонке только select, а в левой CREATE и INSERT

Comment: @eicto, ура, я сделал. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c15e

Только вот лимит комментариев скоро иссякнет.

Comment: начните самообразование [отсюда][1].

    SELECT t.topic, t.date, u.name 
    FROM topics t 
       join users u on t.user_id=u.user_id;

@eicto синтаксис с cross join'ами устаревший. в частности оракл будет ругаться на запросы где будет подозрение на декартово произведение. микрософт тоже против (пруф в википедии).

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c15e/9)

Итак, схема:

```
CREATE TABLE topics(
  topic varchar(255),
  user_id int(11),
  date timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  );
CREATE TABLE users(
  user_id int(11) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_name varchar(30)
  );
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(null,'petya');
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(null,'vasya');
INSERT INTO users  VALUES(null,'robot');

INSERT INTO topics (topic,user_id) VALUES('hello','1');
INSERT INTO topics (topic,user_id) VALUES('hello2','1');
INSERT INTO topics (topic,user_id) VALUES('hello3','2');
INSERT INTO topics (topic,user_id) VALUES('hello4','6');
```

Вернуть только топики с авторами

```
SELECT t.topic,t.date,u.user_name 
    FROM topics t INNER JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id=u.user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c15e/9/0)**:

```
|  TOPIC |                         DATE | USER_NAME |
-----------------------------------------------------
|  hello | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |     petya |
| hello2 | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |     petya |
| hello3 | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |     vasya |
```

Вернуть все топики, если автор не найден, то anonymous

```
SELECT t.topic,t.date,IFNULL(u.user_name,"anonymous") as user_name
    FROM topics t LEFT JOIN users u 
    ON t.user_id=u.user_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c15e/9/1)**:

```
|  TOPIC |                         DATE | USER_NAME                       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  hello | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |                           petya |
| hello2 | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |                           petya |
| hello3 | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |                           vasya |
| hello4 | April, 24 2013 20:49:06+0000 |                       anonymous |
```

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, спасибо ща с join сделаю

Comment: не могу сообразить, что такое t. и u.

Comment: а , это пространства имен отдельных таблиц!

Comment: @Deus видите как sqlfiddle облегчает ответы на вопросы ?

Comment: @eicto, спасибо. С sqlfiddle хоть поработал. Никогда не составлял sql-запросы. phpMyadmin - все мышкой делается, мозгов много не нужно. ))

Comment: А где в sqlfiddle выводятся результаты после select запроса? У меня ничего не появляется. Я нажимаю build schema - все ок, а результатов нет.

Comment: после run sql (там сбоку на кнопочке есть еще и формат вывода)